# Uploading file to webserver

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I am trying to upload files to the server but files are not uploading. User selects a file from document and send to php when user clicks on submit button. I tested it on two devices it always says "forbidden-403". I referred this link-https://www.coderefer.com/android-upload-file-to-server/

Comment: `User selects a file from document`?? From what?

Comment: @greenapps From document